# Question about "relatedTo"

Tags: relatedto

I want to get list of entries in my section `video` related to my current entry

```
{% for video in craft.entries.section('videos').limit('3').relatedTo({targetElement: entry.title, field: 'talents'}) %}
```

problem is `entry.title` is text, but talents is array.

Answer (score 2):

The `relatedTo` parameter accepts an element, the ID of an element, an array if element ids or an object of type `EntryQuery`.

All you need to do is to pass the ID rather than the title

```
targetElement: entry.id
```

Furthermore if you use Craft 3 you might want to execute your query by calling `.all()`
`talents` doesn't contain an array. It contains an object of type `EntryQuery` that can be executed in order to get an array of elements